# How get terms and posts based on TERM meta key?

Tags: wordpress, metadata

I need to add meta data to terms (something like [update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)).

I have created `wp_termmeta` (using [this tutorial](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-term-or-taxonomy-meta-data) with some modifications) table like `wp_postmeta`.

So now this mechanism worked good and i may add/get/delete meta data to any term using [get_metadata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata) / [update_metadata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_metadata) / [delete_metadata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_metadata).

[image]

I may get term meta data based on term object / id etc. **But i need to *get terms/posts based on term meta key***.

**For example:**

I have CPT `book`. Then i have custom tax `writer`. Now i am adding meta data to `writer` - `featured` with possible values `true/false (1/0)`.

**So now i have 2 questions:**

1) How to get all writers (terms from `writer` tax) which are featured (`featured` = `true`)?

2) Ho to get books from CPT `book` belongs to writers which are featured?

**P.S. 1**

Here are [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function. Using args i may get posts based on posts meta key:

```
<?php $args = array(
'meta_key'         => '',
'meta_value'       => ''); ?>
```

Also there are [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) function but without meta key parameters.

Maybe there are some solution in `WP_Query` to get things i need? Maybe there are no built-in solution for my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to get all writers (terms from writer tax) which are featured (featured = true)?**

For this you first need to grab the ID's of the featured terms, and then grab those terms.

```
$featured_writers = get_featured_writers();
```

**How to get books from CPT book with writers who are featured?**

For this I recommend first grabbing the ID's of the featured terms, and then creating a [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object of books who are related to that term. You can then use this [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object in [`The Loop`](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

```
$featured_books = get_books_with_featured_writer();
```

**If you want both featured writers and books with featured writers**

To save duplicate queries (although WP is quite good at caching them anyway), you could do this if you require both the featured writers and the books with featured writers -

```
$featured_writers_ids = get_featured_writer_ids();
$featured_writers = get_featured_writers($featured_writers_ids);
$featured_books = get_books_with_featured_writer($featured_writers_ids);
```

**The code**

Put this code in your `functions.php` files (or any file included by `functions.php`).

Give it a try and let me know if you get problems -

```
function get_featured_writers($featured_writers_ids = null){

    /** Ensure the $featured_writers_ids are set and valid */
    $featured_writers_ids = check_features_writer_ids($featured_writers_ids);
    if(!$featured_writers_ids) :
        return false;
    endif;

    $args = array(
        'fields'    => 'ids',
        'include'   => $featured_writers_ids
    );
    $featured_writers = get_terms('writer', array('include' => $featured_writers_ids));

    return $featured_writers;

}

function get_books_with_featured_writer($featured_writers_ids = null){

    /** Ensure the $featured_writers_ids are set and valid */
    $featured_writers_ids = check_features_writer_ids($featured_writers_ids);
    if(!$featured_writers_ids) :
        return false;
    endif;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'book',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'writer',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $featured_writers_ids
            )
        )
    );
    $books = new WP_Query($args);

    return $books;

}

function get_featured_writer_ids(){

    global $wpdb;

    // This query assumes you've added `termmeta` to the `$wpdb` global. Replace with `$wpdb->termmeta` with `'wp_termmeta'` if you have not.
    $query  = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT `%1$s`.`term_id` FROM %1$s WHERE `meta_key` = 'term_featured' AND `meta_value` = '1'", $wpdb->termmeta);
    $featured_writers_ids = $wpdb->get_col($query);

    return $featured_writers_ids;

}

function check_features_writer_ids($featured_writers_ids = null){

    /** Check to see if any featured writers were passed, or if they should be grabbed now */
    if(is_null($featured_writers_ids)) :
        $featured_writers_ids = get_featured_writer_ids();
    endif;

    /** Ensure that there are featured writers, and that $featured_writers_ids is an array */
    if(is_empty($featured_writers_ids) || !is_array($featured_writers_ids)) :
        return false;
    endif;

    return $featured_writers_ids;

}
```

Comment: hm, this is interesting. Thx. But this solution i already have... I am thinking about built-in functionality... I am wrote P.S. 1 for you in main question.

Comment: This is using built in functionality, and addresses exactly the 2 questions that you asked. You'll end up with a `WP_Query` object for books with featured writers, and an array of `WP_Term` objects for the featured writers. You can't get more build in then that...

Comment: David, i have just wrote P.S. 1 for you. Checkit please. Thx!

Comment: Why i am asking of it: i do not what to "reinvent the wheel". So i may write functions to get all data i need, but maybe there are solutin in WP_Query etc. to make it easy and in right way...

Comment: Ok, I'm assuming that by 'built in' you are actually meaning a simple, no additional functions required, 2 or 3 line solutions. Unfortunately that is not the case. Wordpress cannot cater for every possible scenario when it comes to getting posts/terms, thus they invented things like `$wpdb` to help us query the database. I too like to have fewer functions if possible, but I'm not sure it is possible in your case.